# How to know if user logged in

Tags: functions

I have PHP code

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == 1) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">var logged_in=true;</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">var logged_in=false;</script>';
}?>
```

It always returns `var logged_in=false;`. Where is mistake?

Comment: use proper wordpress API instead of trying to hack things by your own ;)

Comment: The key to use in `$_COOKIE` check is stored in `LOGGED_IN_COOKIE` constants, looks like `wordpress_logged_in_` followed by a hash. To get this, you will have to load WordPress, and if you did, then simply call `is_user_logged_in()` with ease.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">var logged_in=true;</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">var logged_in=false;</script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with caching, shows that user is not logged on cached pages visited before logging.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function to check if the user is or not logged in the Dashboard.

I do not know why you echo out a `<script>` tag, but if you want to integrate *PHP & JavaScript* altogether, I recommend you to take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins.

This way you can pass data from the WordPress Back End to Front End and vice-versa through **AJAX** callbacks.